# CUDA Parallelism inside core

Tags: cuda, gpu

In CUDA, how is the sequential code managed inside a GPU core?

If I have a kernel within a `for` loop, does it execute sequentially or is there logical parallelism?

Answer (score 3):

Sequential code will still be computed sequential, with the only change that all threads will compute this code parallel.

Let's assume following simple kernel (corde written down here, not tested):

```
__global__ void kernel(int *array, int N)
{
  if (threadIdx.x < N)
  {
    // complete for loop is computed parallel for different threads
    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
    {
      // every single thread perfomes this statement 1000 times
      array[threadIdx.x] += i;
    }
  }
}
```

The complete for-loop will be computed parallel for different threads within the same warp.
But every single thread compute this for loop sequential for itself.

Answer (score 0):

All threads in a warp/wavefront take all of the same code branches and calculations together, every step is the same for all threads.

So if 8 threads want branch Z and 24 threads want branch Y, the 8 threads will wait until branch Y is completed and then the 24 threads will wait until branch Z is completed then all 32 will continue together. Physically in the processor core, the threads don't "wait" on the side, they remain together marching through every operation of both branches and the "waiting" threads are hidden from the instruction by a bitmask, but logically and for timing it is the same as waiting.

This is why branching causes poor performance in a GPU. One or two branches can be acceptable but the performance cost grows much faster than linear.